# Using an rvalue reference to index, any benefits?

Tags: c++, containers, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I was wondering if there are any possible benefits to using an rvalue reference argument for indexing into a container object as opposed to a const reference:

```
Foo::bar(T1&& i, T2&& x)
{
  m_data[i].emplace_back(std::move(x));
}
```

Where `m_data` is a `std::unordered_map<T1, std::vector<T2>>`. It seems more natural to me that `i` be of type `const T1&`, but I don't know enough about move semantics to know if `T1&&` has any benefits or not (assume that T1 and T2 are heavy types).

Edit: In my use case T1 is a `std::pair<enums, std::string>` and T2 is a shared_ptr to a custom class.

Comment: That depends on what `T1` is, but, in general, no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks! Why do you say it depends on T1?

Comment: Because it does. Depending on what parameter whatever `m_data` type's `operator[]` overload accepts, there may or may not be an implicit conversion that takes place.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Assuming m_data is a std::unordered_map<T1, T2>.

Comment: @pooya13: You probably mean `std::unordered_map<T1, std::vector<T2>>` (for `emplace_back`).

Comment: Again, that depends on what `T1` and `T2` is.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes that was what I meant :D
T1 is a `std::pair<enums, std::string>` and T2 is a shared_ptr to a custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `T1` and `T2` are template parameters, it is better to use perfect forwarding when your arguments are passed through to other functions.

```
Foo::bar(T1&& i, T2&& x)
{
  m_data[std::forward<T1>(i)].emplace_back(std::forward<T2>(x)));
}
```

Then, it does not matter whether `T1` and `T2` are fundamental types, POD types, or complex classes. It does not matter whether `i` and `x` are passed by lvalue reference or rvalue reference.